# How do I change the value of a global variable inside of a function

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript and I create a global variable. I define it outside of a function and I want to change the global variable value from inside a function and use it from another function, how do I do this?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Just reference the variable inside the function; no magic, just use it's name. If it's been created globally, then you'll be updating the global variable.

You can override this behaviour by declaring it locally using `var`, but if you don't use `var`, then a variable name used in a function will be global if that variable has been declared globally.

That's why it's considered best practice to always declare your variables explicitly with `var`. Because if you forget it, you can start messing with globals by accident. It's an easy mistake to make. But in your case, this turn around and becomes an easy answer to your question.

Comment: This doesn't work for me:

    country = 'foo'
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some-endpoint',
        success: function(data) {
            country = data.country;
        }
    });
    console.log(country) // outputs 'foo'

Comment: @MarkSimpson - the reason it doesn't work is because in your example, the `console.log` is run immediately, but the ajax success function only runs at some point later when the ajax call actually returns a response. This is a fundamental point about the asynchronous nature of ajax: code in closure functions does not run in sequence with the code around it. This is an important to grasp when learning about event-driven code.

Comment: The way to get the console.log to be more accurate in this case would be to put it inside the ajax success function.

Comment: Another of my brilliant insights: double check the spelling and case of the variable name.  It is very easy to miss something as simple as sessionId vs sessionID.

Comment: I've the same problem on these. But finally understood, thanks @Spudley !

Comment: Anyone know why global variables become undefined in image.onload function?

Answer (score 96):

```
var a = 10;

myFunction();

function myFunction(){
   a = 20;
}

alert("Value of 'a' outside the function " + a); //outputs 20
```

Comment: thanks for this awesome simple example. The logic of this was doing my head in. Just got to get used to 4d thinking.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, but why adding this: var global = "Global Variable"; function click(){ global = "Hello World!"; }; console.log(global); return ( <div className="App"> <button onClick={click}>click</button> </div> ); } in react js, the global is not changed to Hello World ?

Comment: When you add `var` before `a` inside the function - `var a=20` -, the global value of a will not change.

Comment: also, if `a` is a function's parameter, it won't change the global variable

Answer (score 39):

Just use the name of that variable.

In JavaScript, variables are only local to a function, if they are the function's parameter(s) or if you declare them as local explicitely by typing the `var` keyword before the name of the variable.

If the name of the local value has the same name as the global value, use the `window` object

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKDx/)

```js
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 3;

function a(y) {
  // y is local to the function, because it is a function parameter
  console.log('local y: should be 10:', y); // local y through function parameter
  y = 3; // will only overwrite local y, not 'global' y
  console.log('local y: should be 3:', y); // local y
  // global value could be accessed by referencing through window object
  console.log('global y: should be 2:', window.y) // global y, different from local y ()

  var x; // makes x a local variable
  x = 4; // only overwrites local x
  console.log('local x: should be 4:', x); // local x
  
  z = 5; // overwrites global z, because there is no local z
  console.log('local z: should be 5:', z); // local z, same as global
  console.log('global z: should be 5:', window.z) // global z, same as z, because z is not local
}
console.log('global x: should be 1:', x); // global x
console.log('global y: should be 2:', y); // global y
console.log('global z: should be 3:', z); // global z
a(10)
console.log('global x: should be 1:', x); // global x, unaltered
console.log('global y: should be 2:', y); // global y, unaltered
console.log('global z: should be 5:', z); // global z, overwritten in function a
```

### Edit

With ES2015 there came two more keywords `const` and `let`, which also affect the scope of a variable ([Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations))

Comment: +1 for describing the name collision between the global and the locally declared variable and how to access it.

Comment: @yunzen, but why adding this: var global = "Global Variable";

function click(){
   global = "Hello World!";
};
console.log(global); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={click}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
} in react js, the `global` is not changed to Hello World ?

Comment: Would anyone mind adding how to do this with _dictionaries_? Declaring `global.value=1` outside then doing `global.value++` inside any function will not increment it. Doing `global['value']+=1` does not help either.

Comment: @scavenger I suppose you should start a new question with an code example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 11):

```
var a = 10;

myFunction(a);

function myFunction(a){
   window['a'] = 20; // or window.a
}

alert("Value of 'a' outside the function " + a); //outputs 20
```

With  **window['variableName']** or **window.variableName** you can modify the value of a global variable inside a function.

Comment: This is the only way I could change the global variable value in angular component !!!

Answer (score 7):

```
<script>
var x = 2; //X is global and value is 2.

function myFunction()
{
 x = 7; //x is local variable and value is 7.

}

myFunction();

alert(x); //x is gobal variable and the value is 7
</script>
```

Comment: Just don't use the `var` keyword inside of the function, then you don't have to deal with `document.getElementById("outside").value = x;`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use **var**

```
var apple = null;
const some_func =()=>{
      apple = 25
}
some_func()
console.log(apple)
```

Comment: Does not work when use async function and await for set value.