# Change value of variable from inside function

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 10;
function(results, done) {
    //some code
    a = 5;
}
console.log(a); //prints 10
```

How do I get the value of a to change to 5?

Comment: I doubt it prints anything, because you have invalid JavaScript code (missing function name). Assuming you define your function properly, you have to call the function before you make the call to `console.log`.

Comment: What is `function(results, done) {` ? is this a section of some callback that you have pasted here? `var a = 10;
(function() {
    //some code
    a = 5;
})();
console.log(a); //prints 5`

Comment: You should probably call the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change value of global variable inside of  function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872006/how-to-change-value-of-global-variable-inside-of-function)

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the function for the code in it to be executed:

```
var a = 10;
function myFunc(results, done) {
    //some code
    a = 5;
}
myFunc();
console.log(a); //prints 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `a` is defined in the same scope as the function, you just call the `function`.

However to call the function you will need to give it a name:

```
function foo(results, done) {
   //some code
   a = 5;
}
foo();
```

Comment: Do you mean "scope" instead of closure? The function *is* a closure, but you cannot say they are defined *in* a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function.

A function will not run until you call it.