# Access value of variable outside of function where it was modified as a result of query - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

How can I use the modified value of my global variable `numRes` outside of the function that modifies its value? 
When I access it after modification, I get only the initial value.

The
[How do I change the value of a global variable inside of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872006/how-to-change-value-of-global-variable-inside-of-function) and [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call?rq=1)
questions describe something similar, but they did not help.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1'); 
// ...

var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

numRes = 0;
query.send(function(response) {
    numRes = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
    console.log(numRes + " results are found - inside query.send"); // correct
    });

// how to get the same value as three lines above?
console.log(numRes + " results are found"); // not correct, gives 0
// setTimeout(console.log(numRes + " results are found - after timeout"), 10000); // does not help

foo = numRes;
// ... code with foo
```

Comment: The answer on AJAX you linked is the solution. It explains your issue in detail.