# Global Javascript variables defined in the function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make variables lat and loc global, but they are always zero.

```
var lat=0;
var loc=0;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     lat = position.coords.latitude;
     loc = position.coords.longitude;
});

alert(lat); // this eqals zero
```

Comment: What does `alert(lat)` say inside the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change value of global variable inside of  function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872006/how-to-change-value-of-global-variable-inside-of-function)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Nopes. This is not that case!

Comment: @PraveenKumar See Spudley's comment on the first answer

Comment: Nice, that's what I explained in my answer! @DavidRobinson! Still not a duplicate of **that** answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it seems that the function does not even start. When I put alert inside function the alert window didn't display.

Comment: Great... So you need to put it to work on a device where it has an access to the location. If you are trying it on chrome on a laptop, it is tricky to get it started. The allow permissions thing doesn't come so easily for location!

Answer (score 2):

That's an **asynchronous** call! Use this way:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    loc = position.coords.longitude;
    alert (lat);
});
```

**Background**

When you are firing `alert(lat)`, the `getCurrentPosition()` wouldn't have fired and your value might have not set. If you wanna do something, put it or call it inside that function.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    loc = position.coords.longitude;
    // Something like this.
    calculate (lat, loc);
});
```