# Is there anyway to change the value of global variable in function and access outside the local scope in js

Tags: node.js, scope, global-variables

Is there anyway to change the value of global variable in function and access the changed value of global variable outside the function in javascript or nodejs...

```
var x=8;
function changed(x)
{
   x=10;
 }
console.log(x);
```

The actual output is 8 but i want the value of x is 10. is it possible in javascript or nodejs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872006/how-do-i-change-the-value-of-a-global-variable-inside-of-a-function

Comment: Remove the parameter from the `changed` function, else reassigning it will only reassign the value tied to the local name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass x then the parameter becomes local to the function, when a variable is global, you can just use it in any function to changes the value of the global variable, and it will reflect everywhere.

```
var x=8;

function changed() {
   x=10;
}
changed(x)
console.log(x);
```