# Is there a way to make a D3 legend change based on user input to radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

My goal is to create a webpage that presents a data-driven legend, and radio buttons.  I would like the user's selection of radio buttons to change the legend.

The complicating factor is that the legend relies on a nesting function, and I can't figure out how to make the "key" of the nesting function responsive to the radio buttons.

Here's are the steps I've taken so far:

- Create the legend (nest data, then attach nest keys to rectangles).
- On the click of the radio button, make d3 select all the rectangles in the DOM.
- Send the radio button's selection to a function called `updateKey`, which contains the nest variable.  Substitute the `d.key` portion of nest with the radio button selection.
- Change the fill attribute of the rectangle to `color(d.key)`.

My problem is that nest variable doesn't seem to change within the `updateKey` function, even though my research on global variables indicates that it [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872006/how-do-i-change-the-value-of-a-global-variable-inside-of-a-function) change.

Code here:

```js
var doc = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`Passed Category    Owner   Dup
    yes msg Hailey  yes
    yes msg Hailey  yes
    yes doc Hailey  yes
    yes doc Robert  yes
    yes msg Laquila yes
    no  spreadsheet Hailey  yes
    `]));

d3.tsv(doc)
  .row(function(d) {
    return {
      Passed: d.Passed,
      Category: d.Category,
      Owner: d.Owner,
      Dup: d.Dup
    };
  })
  .get(function(error, data) {

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .append("g");
    //create a function for applying colours
    var cat20 = d3.schemeCategory20

    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(function(d) {
        return nest(d.key);
      })
      .range(cat20);
    //pick one column of data and nest according to that column
    nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Category
      })
      .sortKeys(d3.descending)
      .entries(data)

    var legend = d3.select("#legend")
      //Make the legend
      .append("svg")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.range(20))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 25 + ")";
      });
    //make the legend squares
    legend.append("rect")
      .data(nest)
      .attr("class", "rect")
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return colors(d.key)
      })
      .style('stroke', "Grey");
    //make the legend text
    legend.append("text")
      .data(nest)
      .attr("x", 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      });

    function updateKey(h) {

      var nest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return (h)
        })
        .sortKeys(d3.descending)
        .entries(data)
    }
   
    d3.selectAll(("input[name='stack']")).on("change", function(d) {
      var colVar = this.value;
      if (colVar == 'Category') {
        d3.selectAll(".rect").style("fill", function(d) {
          updateKey("d['" + colVar + "']")
          return colors(d.key)
        })
      }
    })


  })
```

UPDATE: I have confirmed that the function is retrieving a new nest variable, because when I input `console.log(nest)` in the last block of code, it returns the correct key-value object. However, if I add `console log(d.key)` immediately below `console.log(nest)`, it returns the keys of the nest variable that was set at the beginning of the code. This suggests that `d.key` is somehow not changing, even though nest is changing.  I think I need to set d.key explicitly.

UPDATE 2: My new strategy is to create all the legends, then use the buttons to appear/disappear legends based on class.

Comment: Could you add an active class and change the colour with css instead? .active.legend .rect{fill:pink}

Comment: Not sure.  I also need to change the text, and I don't think css will do that.

Comment: Create working code snipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem here is confusion around the `nest` function and that your `nest` variable isn't holding a reference to that function but your data instead.

That said, I find your code overly confusing and not written to how you should be using `d3` data binding abilities.  So here's my commented refactor *working example*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="radio" id="passed" name="stack" value="Passed" />
    <label for="passed">Passed</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="category" name="stack" value="Category" checked />
    <label for="category">Category</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="owner" name="stack" value="Owner" />
    <label for="owner">Owner</label>

    <div id="chart"></div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="legend"></div>
    <script>
      var doc = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([
          `Passed,Category,Owner,Dup
yes,msg,Hailey,yes
yes,msg,Hailey,yes
yes,doc,Hailey,yes
yes,doc,Robert,yes
yes,msg,Laquila,yes
no,spreadsheet,Hailey,yes`,
        ])
      );

      // had to switch to csv for stacksnippet editor
      d3.csv(doc)
        .row(function (d) {
          return {
            Passed: d.Passed,
            Category: d.Category,
            Owner: d.Owner,
            Dup: d.Dup,
          };
        })
        .get(function (error, data) {

          // container for legend
          var legend = d3
            .select('#legend')
            //Make the legend
            .append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'legend');

          // initial draw
          drawLegend('Category');

          // function to redraw legend
          // based on d3 enter, update, exit
          function drawLegend(currentSelection) {

            // apply nest function for new selection
            let nestedData = d3
              .nest()
              .sortKeys(d3.descending)
              .key(function (d) {
                return d[currentSelection];
              }).entries(data);

            // update selection
            let lu = legend
              .selectAll('g')
              // the key function here is important
              // so that d3 can calculate the enter, update, exit
              .data(nestedData, d => d.key);

            // exit selection
            lu.exit().remove();

            // enter selection
            // add container g
            let le = lu
              .enter()
              .append('g')
              .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
                return 'translate(0,' + i * 25 + ')';
              });

            // on enter add rect
            le.append('rect')
              .attr('class', 'rect')
              .attr('width', 18)
              .attr('height', 18)
              .style('fill', function (d,i) {
                return d3.schemeCategory20[i];
              })
              .style('stroke', 'Grey');

            // on enter add text
            le.append('text')
              .attr('x', 24)
              .attr('y', 9)
              .attr('dy', '.35em');

            // enter + update
            lu = le.merge(lu);

            // on enter or update, change text
            lu.selectAll('text')
              .text(function(d){
                return d.key;
              });
          }

          d3.selectAll("input[name='stack']").on('change', function (d) {
            drawLegend(this.value);
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```